# Не работает голосовой ассистент на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, pyttsx3

Все модули установлены, работаю в Pycharm, код написан правильно, но голоса никого не подает в чем может быть ошибка

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()    
engine.say("Кто ответит тот лучший")    
engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: Прекрасно работает, тестировал на Windows 10, Python 3.7.3, pyttsx3 2.71

Comment: возможно, у вас не установлен голосовой движок для русского языка